# ¿Como empaquetar correctamente un JAR?

Tags: java, netbeans, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

¿Cómo puedo empaquetar correctamente una aplicación con un archivo .json?
Tengo un proyecto con Maven en NetBeans que lee datos de Firebase por medio de un archivo .json, al leer el archivo al correr la aplicación con Netbeans, la aplicación funciona de manera correcta, pero al construir el JAR el archivo conexion.json se guarda en la raíz del JAR entonces las líneas de código no pueden leerlo y no me muestra la información que necesito.

```
        try {
            FileInputStream serviceAccount
                    = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/conexion.json");
            System.out.println(serviceAccount);

            FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                    .setDatabaseUrl("URL-DB")
                    .build();

            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
            db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Object[] options = {"Aceptar"};
            JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Error al leer archivo JSON", "Aviso",
                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                    null, options, options[0]);

        }
    }
```

Dejo las líneas de código de mi pom.xml, estoy construyendo el JAR con unas dependencias que necesito en la aplicación

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.issste</groupId>
    <artifactId>ISSSTEregs</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId> 
                <executions>
                    <execution> 
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals> 
                            <goal>single</goal> 
                        </goals> 
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration> 
                    <archive> 
                        <manifest> 
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath> 
                            <mainClass>Ventanas.Login</mainClass> 
                        </manifest> 
                    </archive> 
                    <descriptorRefs> 
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef> 
                    </descriptorRefs> 
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>AbsoluteLayout</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE160</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-firestore -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-firestore</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.formdev/flatlaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.formdev</groupId>
            <artifactId>flatlaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlgraphics/batik-swing -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sólo necesitas cambiar esta linea:

```java
            InputStream serviceAccount
                    = ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("conexion.json");
```

Este código genera un input stream a partir de un recurso presente en el classpat.

Los archivos en `src/main/resources` van a la raíz del jar. Esto lo lee tanto si está en un jar como si está en la raíz del classpath en un directorio de clases compiladas.

El acceso como archivo solo te sirve cuando quieres obtener un archivo fuera del jar.

En otras palabras, el jar se está empaquetando bien, lo que está mal es el código que quiere obtener el stream para leer el archivo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya cambié esa línea de código y efectivamente funciona pero únicamente corriendo el programa desde Netbeans, corriendo el JAR sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Puedes mostrar cómo estás ejecutando el jar? Asimismo estás seguro que se reconstruyó luego del cambio de código?